# php echo is not working in html

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some trouble getting a php value into a bootstrap button which is in html

This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Samples</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" role="button"><?php echo "Samples"; ?> Stuff</a>
</body>
</html>
```

So instead of the button saying "Samples Stuff" - the button just simple says "Stuff". It is important that the button takes a php value as eventually I will be putting a db value in the button - but I can't even get the basics working

Why is it not working?

Comment: Also you will need to set up a local server to see PHP files on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a locally hosted server. If not, you probably should install XAMPP. Ensure the file has a .php extension, I don't see any other reason why a simple echo would not work.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the file extension ends with .php. Also make sure that your php/apache is configured correctly.

Try and look at your error logs and see if anything is there

Answer (score -2):

Firstly ensure that your file extension is .php secondly make sure you run .php files on a php enabled webserver. Simply viewing php files on your browser will not actually compile the php. This is done in the back-end on your server.